# Is there any way to access a subclass' Designer-generated components container?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, windows-forms-designer, devexpress-windows-ui

When you make a form in Visual Studio, the Designer automatically generates a components container:

```
/// <summary>
/// Required designer variable.
/// </summary>
private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
```

We have a couple dozen forms, all of which share a common base class to make it easy to put in some common functionality ("You have unsaved data, are you sure you want to close this window?" and so on). Each form has its own [BarManager](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsBarManagertopic) component (they have different menus and buttons and so on, so nobody saw a need to have them inherit that component). Now we've realized that we'd like to add an event handler to all of those BarManagers.

I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
public partial class Foo : Form
{
   ...
   private void Foo_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.components.Components.OfType<BarManager>().ToList().ForEach(tb =>
       {
           tb.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(FooHandler);
       });
   }

   protected void FooHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // do stuff
   }
   ...
}
```

If it was in the `Controls` collection that approach would work just fine, but since `components` is private, Foo & its controls have separate collections.

Is there any way to accomplish this without modifying every single subclass? I suspect it can be done with reflection (which I'm not very familiar with), but I would prefer a solution *without* reflection if that's possible.

Comment: I hope you are aware that this will not give you toolbars that might have been created dynamically at runtime?

Comment: @Crono Yep, we don't create any that way so it's OK; they're all created in the Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the designer generates the `components` variable as private, reflection is the only way to go. Of course you can be clever and be sure that reflection will be used only once to fetch the instance that you will thereafter point to with a variable of yours, so that subsequent access will be more efficient.

You could make your own designer code serializer, but I think it's a bit of an overkill. Plus, that won't make existing forms components variable more available (unless you reopen the designer for each of them).

If I may: since every forms only have one toolbar (or so it seems?), why don't you browse the form's collection of controls recursively until you find an instance of it?

**EDIT:**

Since you're using DexExpress then your form will have `DevExpress.XtraBars.BarDockControl` instances placed as controls in the form. They are acting as the containers of your component toolbar objects. Look for those at runtime in `Form.Controls`. They have a `Manager` property that will give you the bar manager they're attached to. Of course from there you'll have access to every toolbars it contains.

Comment: Just realized I oversimplified; they're actually DevExpress BarManager objects, and are not anywhere in the Controls collection as far as I can tell.